# Jquery ASMX Web Service call - send / receive complex types

Tags: javascript, .net, jquery, ajax, asmx

Not sure if it's just the time of day, lack of coffee or over indulgence of sugar from last night.  Besides that I'm trying to get this working. I do not want to change / modify  / add a new web service method.

I have an asmx web service:

```
public UserLogin Login(UserLogin p_objUserLogin)
{
}
```

I need to hook a JQuery ajax call up to that. The UserLogin object is not that complex:

```
public class UserLogin
{
    public UserLogin();

    public string Privileges { get; set; }
    public string ClientCodeID { get; set; }
    public UserDetails User { get; set; }
    public string UserLoginMessage { get; set; }
    public bool Valid { get; set; }
}
```

The UserDetails object is quite large, and includes a lot more data. (Hopefully I don't need to build the entire object tree to get this to work).

```
public class UserDetails
{
    public string CellPhone { get; set; }
    public string Email { get; set; }
    public string EncryptedPassword { get; set; }
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string FullName { get; }
    public string Initials { get; set;
    public bool InService { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public string Password { get; set; }
    public byte[] Signature { get; set; }
    public string SimCard { get; set; }      
    public int UserID { get; set; }
    public string UserName { get; set; }
    public SecurityRole UserSecurityRole { get; set; }
    public Workgroup UserWorkgroup { get; set; }
}
```

The script I'm playing around with:

```
function CallService() {
    var p_objUserLogin = {};
    p_objUserLogin['ClientCodeID'] = "Test";
    var DTO = { 'p_objUserLogin': p_objUserLogin };
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "UtilityServices2006.asmx/Login",
        data: JSON.stringify(DTO),
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        dataType: "json",
        processData: true,
        success: function (msg) {
            alert(msg);
        },
        error: function (req, status, error) {
            alert(req + ", " + status + ", " + error);
        },
        complete: function (req, status) {
            alert(req + ", " + status);
        }
    });

}
```

Any help would be quite amazing.

Comment: do you get a complete fail on the WebMethod call. If not, what does the object look like that you are getting in your Login method?

Comment: The login in method on the server? Usually it's filled with ClientID, UserName, EncryptedPassword. My webservice isn't getting hit at all. Soap logs don't get generated either.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ensure your webservice class and method are decorated to handle incoming ajax/json requests:

```
[ScriptService]
public class MyService: WebService
{
    [WebMethod]
    [ScriptMethod(ResponseFormat = ResponseFormat.Json)]
    public UserLogin Login(UserLogin p_objUserLogin)
    {
    }
}
```

I'm not familiar with the notation you're using to configure your payload object (p_objUserLogin['ClientCodeID'] = "Test";).  I've usually used slightly different notation:

```
p_objUserLogin.ClientCodeID = 'Test';
```

However, that might be a red herring - I'm not a JS-objects expert, so your notation may be perfectly valid.

Finally, I'm not sure if JS will automatically convert your object to JSON (var DTO = { 'p_objUserLogin': p_objUserLogin };).  I use the [json2 library](http://www.json.org/js.html) to explicitly serialize JS objects to JSON:

```
var DTO = { 'p_objUserLogin': JSON.stringify(p_objUserLogin) };
```

Hope this helps you nail down the issue.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I do use JSON.Stringify, but will try moving it into the DTO var like you said.